# Issues with animateWithDuration

Tags: animation, swift

Like many others I'm struggling with getting animateWithDuration to work. The code below is a little test I was trying to run. What I want todo is to add a UIView behind, fade the UIView on top and then remove it. The problem is that the fade animation doesn't last the entire 10 second length (it actually completes instantly) despite the completion block executing 10 seconds later as desired.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong. I'm a beginner so I'm sorry in advance if I'm overlooked something very simple.

Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet  var graphView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        graphView.addSubview(createView(UIColor.greenColor()))
    }

    func createView(color: UIColor) -> UIView {
        let viewToReturn = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 354))
        viewToReturn.backgroundColor = color
        return viewToReturn
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func zoomIn() {

        let viewToRemove = graphView.subviews[0] as UIView

        graphView.addSubview(createView(UIColor.redColor()))

        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
                println("Runs")
                viewToRemove.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: {(bool) in
                if bool {
                    viewToRemove.removeFromSuperview()
                    println("End")
                }
        })

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the new `subview` on the top of the old `subview`. When you call `addSubView` function, the new subview is added on top of the old. This is why the the animation change is not visible. Try adding

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(viewToRemove)
```

before starting the animation.

Or you can directly add your new subview below the old using.

```
self.view.insertSubview(createView(UIColor.redColor()), belowSubview: viewToRemove)
```

Comment: Ah this makes sense. Just went over reading the documents again and it does mention that addSubview places it on top. The other thing I realized I wasn't doing correctly is I had the graphView connected up to a UIScrollView in storyboard -.-

For future reference is there a way to better understand how UIViews are being managed other than trying to print the list of subviews to console?